# MongoDB PHP findAndModify Multiple Performance

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a documents in a collection called `Reports` that are to be processed. I do a query like

```
$collectionReports->find(array('processed' => 0))
```

(anywhere between 50 and 2000 items). I process them how I need to and insert the results into another collection, but I need to update the original Report to set processed to the current system time. Right now it looks something like:

```
$reports = $collectionReports->find(array('processed' => 0));
$toUpdate = array();
foreach ($reports as $report) {
    //Perform the operations on them now
    $toUpdate = $report['_id'];
}
foreach ($toUpdate as $reportID) {
    $criteria = array('_id' => new MongoId($reportID));
    $data = array('$set' => array('processed' => round(microtime(true)*1000)));
    $collectionReports->findAndModify($criteria, $data);
}
```

My problem with this is that it is horribly inefficient. Processing the reports and inserting them into the collection takes maybe 700ms for 2000 reports, but just updating the processed times takes at least 1500ms for those same 2000 reports. Any tips to speed this up? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The processed time doesn't have to be exact, it can just be the time the script is ran (+/- 10 seconds or so), if it would be possible to take the object ($report) and update the time directly like that, it would be better than just searching after the first foreach.

Comment: Why are you using findandmodify here? You are not taking advantage of anything it provides.

Comment: I'm still very new to Mongo, what would be the correct function to use here?

Comment: I would say no, just use a normal `update()`, see if that makes things better to start with

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sammaye, changing from findAndModify() to update() seems to work much better and faster.

Comment: Just an update for future searchers: update is indeed better in this case. However long execution times with findAndModify suggest that your query is not indexed... try running the same query through `find()` and add `explain()` at the end to see the number of scanned records (should be minimal) and indexes it uses.